# How to get from array of objects needed key:value with multiple lines

Tags: reactjs, arrays, filtering

Hello guys I have a table and I need extract specific fields from an array and put them in that table.
Array looks like:

```
my_tags = [
{
    item: 1,
    tags:   {name: 'LandingPage', value: 'true'},
            {name: 'Country', value: 'GB'},
            {name: 'Carrier', value: 'Evri'},
            {name: 'EventCode', value: 'Dispatched'},
},
{
    item: 2,
    tags:   {name: 'LandingPage', value: 'true'},
            {name: 'Country', value: 'USA'},
            {name: 'Carrier', value: 'RoyalMail'},
            {name: 'EventCode', value: 'Dispatched'},
}]
```

Its easy using filter Fn get for example my_tags.name or value:

```
my_tags.tags.filter(item => item.name)
```

But I need get and I don't have enough brain for that ><:

```
my_tags.tags.name === 'Country' + my_tags.tags.name === 'Carrier' //['GB', 'USA', 'Evri', RoyalMail]
```

Comment: To extract the 'Country' and 'Carrier' values from the my_tags array, you can use the `map()` function to create a new array with the desired values.

Comment: Did you try it, can you share an example with my case?  something like tags.map(el => el.name === 'Country') does not work for me

Comment: Check it here: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-nova-r4l0l0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @blaize for help!

```
const countriesAndCarriers = my_tags.map((item => {
  const country = item.tags.find(tags => tags.name === 'Country')
  return country.value
}))
console.log(countriesAndCarriers) //[ 'Evri', 'GB' ], [ 'RoyalMail', 'USA' ]
```

Then we again map countriesAndCarriers:

```
countriesAndCarriers.map(([carrier, country]) => console.log(carrier)) //Evri RoyalMail
```

I see that I don't know JS